# The Crypt::decript function stopped working after the Laravel 4.2 to 5.0 update

Tags: php, laravel, encryption, laravel-5, laravel-4.2

After the update of L4.2 to L5 the function Crypt::decrypt doesn't work for the hashes generated on L4.2, however my APP_KEY still the same.

```
DecryptException in Encrypter.php line 147:
MAC is invalid.
```

My hashes generated after the update does work, but not for the ones before the migration;

Comment: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/daeling-with-decryptexceptioninvalid-data

Comment: Sounds like the default cipher changed between versions 4.2 and 5. I think it was `MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128` back in Laravel 4, while it appears to be `AES-256-CBC` in Laravel 5.

Comment: On L5 I setted the Cipher as MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, to avoid that problem, but still nothing changed. still got error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that your 64 enocded data is being strip down due to column length and I think you are storing something relatively big. I just reproduced your error by adding a very large cache value into the database. Make the following changes inside your schema, rollback and rerun the migration:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateCacheTable extends Migration {

    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('cache', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->string('key')->unique();
            $table->longText('value');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('cache');
    }

}
```

The record you pasted previously giving me a NULL and I think it is because it is striped down.

After migrating the `cache` table. Put the same cache value and read back hopefully you will not get error this time. Finger Crossed!

Source: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/daeling-with-decryptexceptioninvalid-data

Comment: Don't post link-only answers. If something in the link answers the question, post that here along with the link.

Comment: @astratyandmitry the max length the strings are 220 and my migration is set to:

    $table->string('account_number', 255);

And my L4.2 hashes does not decrypt

Comment: You need to change `$table->string('account_number')` to `$table->longText('account_number')`

Comment: @astratyandmitry, I make this changes and not solve problem. I try install in other folder the project with L4 and create a Command to decrypt and save on other table, but not work.